# Get Msgbox 3mins later after clicking a commandbutton1 vba

Tags: timer

I am really stuck with one of my project. I need to get msgbox appearing 3mins later once clicked on commandbutton1.
I have a button which copies the text "I will be back in 3minutes" now I need to have a pop msg after 3minutes reminding user with popmsg "your time is up"

Answer (score 0):

I tested 10 seconds interval, and it worked.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'any previous stuff
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "RemindMe"
End Sub
```

The following  subroutine is in a module.

```
Sub RemindMe()
MsgBox "your time is up!"
End Sub
```

Meanwhile, the Excel window doesn't get frozen, you can still operate on the worksheet.